Резервное копирование и восстановление файла бд SQLite на андроид (kotlin)
Делаю небольшую программу с sqlite, мне нужно чтобы можно было базу данных сохранить а затем при необходимости загрузить снова. Я новичок в программировании, поэтому все дается трудно. После длительного поиска получился вот такой код, база вроде сохраняется в папке загрузки, но не могу ее потом загрузить обратно в sqlite, и при выбора файла не получается отфильтровать по расширению. Не понимаю как сохранить файл обратно в бд по uri.
    private fun saveDb() { // сохранение бд в папке загрузка
            val cursor = sqliteServer.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL);",null)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "AS")
            }
            val dstUri = applicationContext.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            if (dstUri != null) {
                val src = FileInputStream(applicationContext.getDatabasePath("AS"))
                val dst = dstUri.let { applicationContext.contentResolver.openOutputStream(it) }
                src.copyTo(dst!!)
                src.close()
                dst.close()
                showToast("База сохранена в папке ,Загрузка, на устройстве")
        } else showToast("Не удалось сохранить базу данных")
        }
    
         private fun dialogOpenFile(){  // Диалог выбора файла бд
             val intent = Intent()
                 .setType("*/*")
                 .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите файл базы данных"), 1)
         }
       @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
               val selectedFilename = data?.data
           restoreDatabase(selectedFilename!!)
        }
    }

    private fun restoreDatabase(uri: Uri) {  // замена файла
        try {
            sqliteServer.close() // Close app database
            val dbpath = sqliteServer.openHelper.readableDatabase.path
            val dbFile = File(dbpath!!)
            val bkpFile = uri.path?.let { File(it) }
            bkpFile!!.copyTo(dbFile, true)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            showToast(e.toString())
        }
    }


вероятно, вас сбивает с толку отсутствие ключевого знания: в sqlite база данных - это файл. один файл. и в нём база данных. и всё.

Как я понимаю файл базы имеет расширение .sqlite, в моем случае файл AS.sqlite. При копировании он появляется в папке загрузки но я не могу его скопировать обратно в базу, вот я и спрашиваю что я не так написал в коде ? и он не работает.

я не могу его скопировать обратно в базу - файл невозможно «скопировать обратно в базу». это вообще нонсенс: «скопировать файл обратно в файл». ведь вся «база данных» - это содержимое одного файла.

Так как же можно восстановить информацию в бд, например после переустановки андроид на смартфоне ?

У вас явно что-то прилетает в catch (e: IOException) при попытке перезаписать файл, там и ищите проблему. Предположу что банально файл залочен и БД надо сначала закрыть, а уже потом пытаться перезаписать. И касательно расширений, называйте свой файл как хотите, хоть 'MyDb.sqlite.db.123', Андроид построен на Линукс, расширения не имеют никакого значения.

Выдает ошибку NoSuchFileException: / document/msf:3354:The source...... Я немного код сократил.

Мне кажется что я не правильно передаю путь, но не понимаю что исправить.

uri.path не является реальным путём файла и даже если бы он был таковым у вашего приложения нет к нему прямого доступа. Вы должны так же как и при сохранении получить поток через ContentResolver:
    private fun restoreDatabase(uri: Uri) {  // замена файла
        try {
            sqliteServer.close() // Close app database
            val dbpath = sqliteSever.openHelper.readableDatabase.path
            applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { bkpStream ->
                FileOutputStream(dbpath!!).use { bkpStream.copyTo(it) }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            showToast(e.toString())
        }
    }


Спасибо большое за подсказку.  Может знаете, как сделать что бы при выборе был виден только файл бд  ?

С этим проблемно - предусмотрен фильтр по mime-type (при запросе файла нужно добавить его в интент: intent.setType("application/vnd.sqlite3"), но нет никакой гарантии что проводник, которым пользователь будет выбирать файл поддерживает это вообще, что этот тип известен в этой версии ОС и был правильно определён/задан при создании файла.

Понятно. Еще раз спасибо за помощь. Вопрос решен.
